# What do these equations on Bayesian regression (MAP) from Chapter 3.3 in PRML by Bishop mean?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, prior, posterior

[image]
[image]

This was taken from Ch 3.3 on Bayesian Linear Regression from *Pattern Recognition in Machine Learning* by Bishop.

Apparently the posterior can be described by eq 3.49. Eq 3.48 represents the prior with Gaussian distribution with mean $$m_0$$ and variance $$S_0$$

What I'm struggling to understand are equations 3.50 and 3.51. I assume they're suppose to represent the mean of over n samples and inverse variance over n samples, but how did the author get to these calculations?